# Why is string.match/find not locating all capital letters?

Tags: string, lua

I'm trying to locate all the capital letters in a string with Lua. Right now, this is what I have:

```
local str = "CatCook"
print(string.find(str,"%u+"))
```

The problem, though, is that, despite the fact that I'm using `+`, the function is only finding the first capital letter.

Output: `1  1`

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: `%u+` simply finds a the first run of upper case characters. what you want `%l%u` which finds the points where a lowercase char proceeds an uppercase one.

Comment: I didn't know you could stack identifiers like that. That helps a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It did exactly what you asked. `string.find` finds the *first match* in the given string. The first sequence of characters that matches a pattern of `\u+` is the first character. Pattern matching matches contiguous sequences of characters.

If you want to extract every sequence of characters that matches a pattern, you need to use `string.gmatch`.

Comment: Okay, that helps. So let me further explain my problem. Now that I've located all the capital letters, I need to insert a space between each one of them (ignoring the first one), so that the resulting string is "Cat Cook". How can I get the string position through gmatch?

Comment: @ChrisLallo: First, that's a different question. Second, why do you need the string position? It seems to me that what you want is to find every instance of a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter, and replace it with the same letters with a space between them. That's a job for `gsub`. Look it up in the docs, along with more details about pattern captures and how `gsub` can use them.